# Jakarta Bean Validation - Conditional constraint

Tags: bean-validation

I have a set of classes like this pretty simple example

```
public class CreditTransfer {
  private String messageId;
  private Party sender;
  private Party receiver;
  private BigDecimal amount;

  //getters and setters
}
public class Party {
  private String name;
  private PostalAddress address;
  private Account account;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Is there a way to conditionally check that address is null only for sender nested object in CreditTransfer class, without implementing a class level constraint?
Obviously if I annotate with @Null the address field of Party class it must be always null, even for receiver, where it must be @NotNull instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to go with `@ConvertGroup`. You'll need two groups for sender/receiver cases:

```java
    interface AddressRequired {}
    interface AddressForbidden {}
```

then in your party class you'd do something like

```java
public class Party {
    @NotNull(groups = AddressRequired.class) // for receiver
    @Null(groups = AddressForbidden.class)   // for sender
    String address;
}
```

and finally, in the transfer class you convert default group to the one you need:

```java
public static class Transfer {
    @ConvertGroup(to = AddressForbidden.class) // from = Default.class is set by default
    @Valid
    Party sender;
    @Valid
    @ConvertGroup(to = AddressRequired.class)
    Party receiver;
}
```

For more details on converting groups see the reference - [Group conversion](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-group-conversion)

Comment: Thank you mark. Actually "in the real world" I have 125 jaxb classes, automatically generated through xjc from a XML schema. This means that the "real" Party class is nested in several other classes with different validation logic and I will have to selectively annotate with annox all nested objects. Anyway, even though it will be boring, I'm pretty sure that your approach is the right one. Thank you again

Comment: You could also go with a `@ScriptAssert`. That would be something like `@ScriptAssert(lang = "groovy", script = "_this.sender.address == null")` -- you might end up with fewer changes. Also, you could build more complex scripts, but I'd probably use one annotation per condition. I haven't suggested that initially since you didn't want to have class constraints ...